# Mobile Mutitouch Buttons in Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, flex4, blackberry-playbook

I have three buttons with sound effects in a mobile adobe air device (PlayBook in this case - supports up to 4 points of multitouch).

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:SoundEffect id="Sound1" source="@Embed(source='assets/Sound1.mp3')" />
    <mx:SoundEffect id="Sound2" source="@Embed(source='assets/Sound2.mp3')" />
    <mx:SoundEffect id="Sound3" source="@Embed(source='assets/Sound3.mp3')" />

</fx:Declarations>

<s:Button interactionMode="touch" x="14" y="60" width="295" height="145" label="Button1" mouseDownEffect="{Sound1}"/>
<s:Button interactionMode="touch" x="362" y="60" width="295" height="145" label="Button2" mouseDownEffect="{Sound2}"/>
<s:Button interactionMode="touch" x="713" y="60" width="295" height="145" label="Button3" mouseDownEffect="{Sound3}"/>
```

All the buttons work but how do I let the user press all three at once? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran on creationComplete:

```
        protected function init():void
        {
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

        }
```

Then used an image for a button since buttons work but only one button shows animation for some reason:

```
<s:Image id="ui_btnLowTom" source="{imageOut.source}" 
         x="14" y="60" width="295" height="145" touchBegin="ui_btnLowTom.source = imageOver.source; LowTomPlay(event)"
         touchEnd="ui_btnLowTom.source = imageOut.source" />
```

And the actual handler:

```
        protected function LowTomPlay(event:TouchEvent):void
        {
            lowTomSndChannel=lowTomSnd.play();              
        }
```

So yes - flex does support multi-touch....

Comment: `since buttons work but only one button shows animation for some reason` — Flex `components` don't support multi-touch. You have to use hacks like this. And this is only a case with 3 buttons.

Comment: Flex buttons actually do go through their handlers in a multi touch environment but don't animate is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Flex components don't support multi-touch.